# form helper wont render check_box field with inherited objects

Tags: forms, inheritance, activerecord, checkbox, ruby-on-rails-4

### Problem:

I want to build a form with a checkbox using the form helper.
My BlogPost has a boolean attribute called 'approved'. This model inherits from another model of mine (Post) instead of the ActiveRecord::Base. In this configuration I get a NoMethodError.

### Files:

Form with checkbox:

```
<%= form_for @blog_post do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
  <!-- throws undefined method `approved' for #<BlogPost:0x00000002600d40> --> 
  <%= f.check_box :approved %>**
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

BlogPost controller:

```
  # GET /blog_posts/new
  def new
    @blog_post = BlogPost.new
  end
```

Post model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

BlogPost model:

```
class BlogPost < Post
end
```

'approved' is an attribute of the BlogPost class. The Post class has some additional attributes I want to use in the BlogPost class. There is also an AnswerPost (< Post) class.

### What I tried:

The doc for the [check_box](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-check_box) method confuses me and the check_box_tag helper also does not work for me. Migration is fine too. 
The 'approved' param is permitted:

```
params.require(:blog_post).permit(:approved)
```

### A clue:

Strange thing for me is: 
**When BlogPost inherits from ActiveRecord::Base instead of Post the form helper works!** Did I miss something essential here?

Comment: Is this a single table inheritance? Or are you having different tables for BlogPost and Post?

Comment: I have different tables. I didn't knew about single table inheritance. I just thought the rails backround magic will do it.

Comment: Ok... Since there are different table, rails would pick the Post table and create form for its column attributes. Hence error, since approved column is not in posts table

Comment: This makes sense. I will look into the STI stuff and try it today. If it works I am glad to accept an answer of yours ;-) thanks so far.

Comment: Yes that was it! I never used inheritance in rails before. Now I understand it. Many Thanks!